# Beating the Hermit mission in Ring Runner

Tags: ring-runner-fots

I haven't been having much difficulty with the Ring Runner campaign until now, but the Hermit seems to be disproportionally more difficult to damage. Am I missing an alternative method of beating the mission? I have tried rogue and fighter hulls.

Comment: I made a tag for it, but I had to abbreviate it. The full name was too long for a tag.

Comment: Thank you kindly. Just `ring-runner` would work fine as well. There aren't any other games by that name that I know of.